# Cannot find TypeScript library module under a folder

Tags: typescript, npm, package

I am authoring a TypeScript NPM package by following [a tutorial here](https://www.tsmean.com/articles/how-to-write-a-typescript-library/)

The code can be found here

https://github.com/envoy/loglevel-file-logger/tree/e4093715b5d06f4c7df9e022f3cbdba160929b02

Then I published the NPM package [here](https://www.npmjs.com/package/loglevel-file-logger)

Now, I can install the package via

```
npm install loglevel-file-logger
```

and use it in my TypeScript project like this

```
import setupLogger from 'loglevel-file-logger'
```

It works perfectly. However, when I am trying to import a non-index file from my package, like this

```
import FetchBlobWriter from 'loglevel-file-logger/FetchBlobWriter'
```

Then you will see tsc complains

```
[ts] Cannot find module 'loglevel-file-logger/FetchBlobWriter'.
```

If you look into the compiled JS code, you will find that the typing file for `FetchBlobWriter` is indeed existing at [`js/FetchBlobWriter.d.ts`](https://github.com/envoy/loglevel-file-logger/blob/e4093715b5d06f4c7df9e022f3cbdba160929b02/js/FetchBlobWriter.d.ts)

Any idea why TypeScript fail to find the module when the `.d.ts` file is there?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's because if you import from the root, like `loglevel-file-logger`, TS will try to import from `node_modules/loglevel-file-logger/index.(js|ts)` or will check the the modules `main` property from the `package.json`. You set the later to `dist/index.js`, which is correct.

**But**, if you want to import a submodule it will the resolve the path from the `root` folder of the module. Not the folder that may or may not be part of the `main` property. Meaning, `'loglevel-file-logger/FetchBlobWriter'` will resolve to `node_modules/loglevel-file-logger/FetchBlobWriter`. TS correctly informs you that there is no module/file, since it is hosted inside the `dist` folder. So importing from `'loglevel-file-logger/dist/FetchBlobWriter'` should work.

Here is a article to give you more information about node's path resolution: https://www.bennadel.com/blog/2169-where-does-node-js-and-require-look-for-modules.htm

Comment: awesome! thank you so much. By the way, is there a way to strip the `dist` part in the npm package so that I don't need to import it from `dist` folder?

Comment: You have to create a custom script AFAIK. Maybe this helps http://davidwells.io/publishing-flat-npm-packages-for-easier-import-paths-smaller-consumer-bundle-sizes/